# What is Hi-Pot parameter for transformer?

Tags: transformer, hipot

From the [datasheet](https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/api/open/part-attachments/datasheet/pa1276nlt) of [PA1276NLT EP13 Series SMT Transformer, up to 60W](https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/part/pa1276nlt):

[image]

I see Hi-Pot parameter of transformer with  (not working isolation voltage provided).  Does it mean constant working isolation voltage the same?

Comment: Does [USERS GUIDE TO HIPOT TESTING](https://incompliancemag.com/article/users-guide-to-hipot-testing/) help?

Comment: looks working is about 2 times less, if I understood correctly

Comment: Please link to the source for the image included in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Constant working isolation voltage and HiPot are two different things:

The **constant working isolationg voltage** is typically what you would use to design your circuit (or actually the other way around: choose parts with a rating fitting your application).

**HiPot** is an additional test for  high voltage transients. This parameter guarantees that the dielectric leakage at this voltage does not exeed some specific leakage current during short transients. The maximum allowed transient duration and the height of the leakage current can vary between manufacturers and testing standards (leakage at the rated voltage might be as low as a few hundred µA or as large as tens of mA).
The HiPot voltage rating exists to guarantee some sufficient margin from the typical working voltage until your design blows up due to transients. Do not design your circuit to constantly run at HiPot rating.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what if constant working isolating voltage missed in datasheets?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure about this, as there is really no data for that in the datasheet. But from the typical applications and voltages for this transformer I would _assume_ that it is not made to withstand high isolation voltages for a long time.

Comment: In a typical floating circuit when there is a large buildup of differential voltage over the transformer the tiny leakage current might be sufficient to "pull" the floating circuit closer to ground.

Comment: @Pinus The [PA1276NLT](https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/part/pa1276nlt) product page contains both ``Input Voltage Range (V) : 30-57`` and ``Input Voltage (V) : Low Voltage (4-80V)``. I'm not sure why two voltage ranges are given, nor how that related to the _Constant working isolation voltage_.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Probably two different example designs. This transformer is intended for use in dc-dc converters, and the actual input/output ratio is variable and not necessarily tied to the turns ratio of the transformer.